# Enviar dados pelo Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá!

No form do `html` eu faço o seguinte:

```
<div class="container jumbotron" ng-controller="crudCtrl">
   <form role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nome" id="">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="sexo">Sexo:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sexo" id="sexo">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="data">Data Nascimento:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dataNascimento" id="data">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="pais">País:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pais" id="pais">
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="Cadastrar()">Salvar</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

E no angular o seguinte:

```
var app = angular.module("crud", []);
app.controller("crudCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.Cadastrar  = function(data) {
        $scope.MostrarTabela = true;

        $scope.nome = data.nome;
        $scope.sexo = data.sexo;
        $scope.datanasc = data.dataNascimento;
        $scope.pais = data.pais;
    }
});
```

Está errado o jeito que estou enviando os dados para o `controller`?

Pois apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Cannot read property 'nome' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu `input` deve ser assim:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.nome" id="">
```

Com isso, dentro do seu `controller` você poderá acessar cada propriedade como uma array, da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.cadastro.nome;
$scope.cadastro.sexo;
//Etc...

//Ou seguindo pelo seu exemplo
$scope.nome = $scope.cadastro.nome
```

Assim você também não precisa mais definir o objeto `data` na função, ficando assim:

```
$scope.Cadastrar = function() { //Sem o data aqui
    //Função aqui
}
```

---

O método mais "correto", ou que pelo menos é o mais comum (e eu prefiro usar) seria de passar o os valores através do ng-submit e acessá-los sem precisar delimitar um $scope para cada campo como você fez, mas tudo depende do uso que você pretende fazer do formulário. Mas seria assim:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="Cadastrar(cadastro)">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.nome" id="">
   </div>

   // Demais campos aqui

   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Ai sim você poderá usar o `controller` como está usando agora.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem esse jeito "cadastro.nome", não funciona mais utilizando o data? e como faço para inserir em uma tabela no html5 através e exibir com o ng-repeat?

Comment: @novato editei minha resposta

Comment: show!... do jeito que fiz, coloquei em diversa variáveis no scope.. para exibir isso num ng-repeat eu teria que colocar numa unica variavel do scope e depois "percorrer" ela, certo?

Comment: Seria o modo mais prático. Vale lembrar também que ao criar diversos `$scope` ele irá gerar um impacto na performance (se for passado para a view), logo, não é a melhor a opção.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, está errado.

Quando você declara sua função no controller, você diz que irá receber um parâmetro, nesse caso `data` - isso não está errado.

```
$scope.Cadastrar  = function(data) { ... }
```

O problema está no `ng-click` na tua view, você está chamando a função `Cadastrar`, mas sem passar parâmetro algum.

```
ng-click="Cadastrar()"
```

Quando você tenta acessar o objeto `data` no controller, ele está vazio, não possui nenhuma das propriedades que você tentou acessar.

**Como corrigir?**

Simples, primeiro, no `ng-model` dos `inputs` crie um objeto, por exemplo `pessoa`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pessoa.nome">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pessoa.sexo">
```

E no `ng-click` passe o objeto esperado.

```
ng-click="Cadastrar(pessoa)"
```

Dessa maneira, você irá receber o objeto no controller e não terá o erro.

Comment: funciona também! se eu pudesse te pontuar eu pontuaria! mas não tá deixando! Obrigado!